# How do I write a Bigquery federated query towards postgres tables?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm confused about the federated query syntax. I'm able to query for metadata with the default connection query in bq console:

`SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("connection-id", "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;");`

But I want to query the tables. So I try:

`SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("connection-id", "SELECT * FROM my_postgres_table;");`

Then the console shows me this:

```
PostgreSQL type  in column type is not supported in BigQuery. You can cast it to a supported type by PostgreSQL CAST() function. at [1:15]
```

How do I write this query to get table results back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your external query contains a data type that is unsupported in BigQuery, the query will fail immediately. You can cast the unsupported data type to a different supported MySQL or PostgreSQL data type.

- **Unsupported PostgreSQL data types**: money, time with time zone, inet, path, pg_lsn, point, polygon, tsquery, tsvector, txid_snapshot, uuid, box, cidr, circle, interval, jsonb, line, lseg, macaddr, macaddr8
- **Resolution**: Cast the unsupported data type to STRING.
- **Example**: SELECT CAST('12.34'::float8::numeric::money AS varchar(30)); This command casts the unsupported data type money to STRING.

See more for [Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#limitations) and [Data type mappings](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#data_type_mappings)